# GitHub CLI : --template option is not supported with --team option

Tags: github, github-cli

I would like to be able to create with [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com), from my terminal, a remote repository in an organization (of which I am an *Owner*) from a template that is in that same organization. The problem is that I'm getting an error message saying that the `team` option is not supported with the `template` option. This seems so limited to me. Is there any way around this limitation?

Here is my command:

```sh
gh repo create Demo  --template="https://github.com/hepl-mmi/template-teacher.git" --private --clone --team="hepl-mmi"
```

Comment: According to [this issue in the tools' repository](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2184#issuecomment-744595981) it's not possible. But the issue is closed, did you try an updated version of GitHub CLI?

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to generate a private repository on an organization from another template repository then you have to prefix the repository name with the organization name. In my case it is necessary to write `hepl-mmi/Demo` instead of just writing `Demo`. You also have to remove the `team` parameter. So the complete command becomes :

```
gh repo create hepl-mmi/Demo  --template="https://github.com/hepl-mmi/template-teacher.git" --private --clone
```